# Android webview with GCM

Tags: google-cloud-messaging, android-webview

Hi I am a beginner in android development.

I have implemented a simple webview in an app to directly get my website displayed into my app. I like to implement push notifications to my app. Did a research and found out that I can use GCM. GCM has two parts writing code for server and client.

Unfortunately I don't understand where to start from. It would be great if provided with a git source with a proper documentation. Software in use: Eclipse

Comment: Any reason you are still using Eclipse and not using Android Studio?

Comment: just that i am a beginner and well experienced in eclipse.

Comment: I would recommend using Android studio especially for a beginner

Answer (score 0):

For a sample android application;
On [GCM Getting Started](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start) Page get the project as;

```
git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services.git
```

To send push mesages to this application. [GCMNotifier](https://github.com/ykartal/GCMNotifier) on Github may help you